# Sinônimos de Tags

Tags: suporte, tags

Olá, gostaria de saber mais como funciona esse recurso, achei um pouco vago o conteúdo [desse link](http://br.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms).

Recentemente discutindo o padrão para tags das perguntas sobre Laravel chegamos a conclusão que 5 tags talvez fossem insuficientes para identificar a linguagem ([php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)), o *framework* ([laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel)), a versão ([laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4)) e ainda o componente ([laravel-eloquent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-eloquent)), restando apenas uma tag para o usuário adicionar livremente.

Talvez o recurso de Sinônimos seja útil nesse problema.

Comment: A pergunta é "Deve `lavarel` ser sinônimo de `lavarel4`?"? Sou contra pois versões novas surgirão em algum momento e o sinônimo perderia a validade. Muitas das questões que vejo sobre o lavarel não dependem explicitamente da versão e a resposta seria a mesma ou muito parecida para uma versão diferente. Uma solução é por apenas `lavarel` nessas.

Comment: Não Guilherme, a pergunta é como funciona o recurso "sinônimo de tags", assim como descrito na primeira linha da pergunta, laravel4, laravel5, etc é que seriam sinonimos de laravel. então poderia-se usar apenas laravel4 ou laravel5 na pergunta

Comment: Qual parte você não entendeu bem? Em linhas gerais, quando a tag B é transformada em sinônimo de A, todas as perguntas com B passam a exibir A em vez de B. Tem uma explicação mais completa, em inglês, em http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work

Comment: é isso que estava em dúvida, se na pergunta irá aparecer a tag principal ou o sinônimo, seria interessante a pergunta exibir a tag [tag:laravel4] e a tag [tag:laravel] conter todas as peguntas das "sub-tags"

Comment: @bfavaretto ainda não tenho as permissões adequadas, e ainda não existem sinônimos no nosso SO, você poderia cria laravel4 como sinônimo de laravel para vermos como funciona? obrigado!

Comment: Eu acho que eles não vão mudar a maneira como as tags funcionam, ou seja, se laravel4 for sinônimo de laravel, o site vão sempre mostrar laravel. Porém acho que no BD a informação da tag realmente usada pelo usuário fica preservada.

Comment: Eu também não posso criar o sinônimo, precisa ter um placar de pelo menos 5 (votos) na tag em questão, e eu não tenho... Olhando a [lista de usuários da tag](http://br.stackoverflow.com/tags/laravel/topusers), entendo que o Zuul cumpre ambos os requisitos (rep mínima e pontuação mínima), vou ver se consigo pedir para ele.

Comment: @bfavaretto entendo, estou perto da permissão (faltam 103 pontos).
acho que uma pergunta deveria exibir a tag jdk-7 e a mesma ser sinônimo de jdk. Podemos abrir solicitar isso?

Comment: Se entendi o que você quer, é uma inversão de como o sistema funciona hoje. E acho que se mudarem isso, muda em todos os sites da rede. Você pode, é claro, abrir um pedido de [meta-tag:novo-recurso], mas a chance de eles recusarem é alta. Se for um pedido só para criar o sinônimo, o Gabe pode fazer.

Comment: @bfavaretto é exatamente isso, penso que é mais útil para a pergunta exibir a versão `jdk-7` do que apenas `jdk` mas também não é legal mater as tags soltas, já que são praticamente a mesma coisa, exceto pela versão.
Se eu fizer o pedido de criação da tag, automaticamente iríamos perder a informação de qual versão está sendo usada pelo usuário, já que a tag é que estava indicando.

Comment: Bom, podemos fazer uma experiência para ver o que acha. Se não gostarmos do resultado, acho que o Gabe pode desfazer. Eu pedi para o Zuul vir olhar aqui, talvez ele esteja propondo o sinônimo para laravel (ainda precisaríamos votar no sinônimo).

Comment: Eu estou aqui, mas estou a resolver um problema num servidor neste momento... tenho um cliente aos berros :D Logo que termine, vou ler com atenção os comentários todos! Ou digam-me o que precisam que eu faço à confiança :P

Comment: @bfavaretto Se bem entendi a ideia é criar `laravel4` como sinonimo de `laravel`, correto?

Comment: Mas já ficou decidido que essas tags são sinônimas mesmo?

Comment: @bigown Acho que não... mas pelo que entendi eles queriam fazer um teste a ver que tag é que ia aparecer na pergunta... talvez discutir o assunto primeiro antes de tomar ação!

Comment: É, acho que me precipitei. Nem o próprio hernandes parece  aceitar as consequências de laravel4 ser sinônimo de laravel. E de fato vai contra o que foi falado até agora. O problema é que não sei *quando* chegaremos a uma conclusão sobre essa questão.

Comment: @bfavaretto correto! se a tag apacer na pergunta apenas como laravel quando alguem postar com a tag laravel4, então perderíamos a informação da versão em uso.

Comment: Consegui encontrar algo Legal pessoal, vejam:

1) Lista de sinônimos do SO Global: 
http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

2) a Tag [tag:javascript-runtime] é sinônimo de [tag:javascript] e mesmo assim:

3) podemos ver a o sinônimo em algumas perguntas:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-runtime

4) ao tentarmos abrir a tag sinonimo, se a mesma não contiver perguntas o navegador é redirecionado para a tag principal:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gvim

Comment: @Zuul, consegue criar [tag:laravel4] como sinônimo de [tag:laravel] pra vermos se o comportamento do site pt será o mesmo?

Comment: Devo conseguir, deixa só o @bigown manifestar-se para eu evitar um "arraial de porrada" ;)

Comment: vou editar a pergunta com as informações que econtrei

Comment: @hernandes javascript-runtime ainda não é sinônimo, é uma sugestão de sinônimo.

Comment: a correto @bfavaretto, quer dizer que é realmente como pensamos no início.

Comment: Particularmente acho melhor perguntar para a equipe (em português para o Gabe ou, se preferirem testar uma outra forma aqui ou no MSO, em inglês para permitir que seja respondida sem atravessador). Não gosto da ideia de fazer um teste de algo que sabemos que tem chances de trazer problemas. Se não sabemos como funciona, não sabemos que problemas isso trás. Mas se quiserem fazer, ok. Neste caso, polidamente, lavo minhas mãos :)

Comment: Concordo @bigown posso fazer a pergunta em inglês aqui no Meta PT?

Comment: Acho que é uma forma de testar como funcionaria perguntando em inglês, já que no momento que a equipe resolve algo, eles respondem em inglês diretamente pra nós. Esse é um teste que não causa mal. Se for mal recebido (o que eu não acredito), é só não fazer de novo. Idealmente seria bom colocar a tradução para não excluir ninguém. Mas qualquer pessoas poderia fazer isso por você também.

Comment: @hernandes acho que não só pode como deve. O ideal é ter as duas línguas. Tenho a impressão que como o Gabe deve estar sobrecarregado com algo (mal vejo por aqui) o ideal seria facilitar a vida da equipe do SE. Por acaso, veja esse link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214277/foreign-language-meta-questions-shouldnt-be-migrated/214282#214282

Comment: Aqui está o link para a pergunta.
http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/improvement-on-tag-system