# Melhorias no sistema de tags

Tags: suporte, tags

Oi, estou postando essa questão também em inglês para a equipe da Stack Exchange.

Essa comunidade teve uma [discussão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/sinonimos-de-tags) sobre o sitema de tags, mas especificamente sobre os sinônimos de tags, o exemplo dado foi a tag [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) que tem uma espécie de ramificação para mostrar a versão em questão e o componente ( [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4), [laravel-component](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-component) ).

O problema principal é que se criarmos [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) como sinônimo de [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) automaticamente a tag [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) não será exibida na questão, apenas [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel).
Fazendo isso estamos perdendo algumas informações sensíveis sobre a própria questão, como a versão e o componente.

Existe alguma forma de relacionar as tags, mas mostrar o sinônimo usado da tag usado na pergunta?

Então, quando um usuário visitar página da tag, todas as questões que usam as tags sinônimo seriam exibidas.

Hoje usamos ambas as tags na pergunta, mas uma questão comum irá incluir alog como 4 tags, exemplo: [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) [laravel-somecomponent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-somecomponent) e como vocês já sabem, o limite de 5 tags estará praticamente esgotado.

---

#### English version

I'm posting this question also in English for the Stack Exchange Staff.

This community had a [discussion](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/487/sinonimos-de-tags) about the tag system, more specifically about tag synonymous, the example given was the [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) tag that has some kind of ramification to show version and component ( [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4), [laravel-component](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-component) ).

The main problem is if we create [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) as synonymous of [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) automatically the [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) will not be showed in the question, only [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel).
Doing this we are loosing some sensitive information about the question itself, like version and component.

Is There any way to relate the tags, but show the used tag synonymous on the question?

So, when a user visit the tag page, all the questions that uses a tag synonymous will be showed.

Today we are using both tags on the question, but a common question will include like four tags, example: [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) [laravel-somecomponent](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-somecomponent) and as you already know, the limit of 5 tags are almost full at that time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em uma aparição no nosso bate-papo, o [Shog9 comentou sobre este assunto](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/conversation/shog9-sobre-tags-de-versao). Em resumo, ele disse o seguinte:

1. **É preferível utilizar sempre a tag neutra (neste caso, [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel)), e acrescentar a tag da versão específica somente em casos em que a versão for relevante para a pergunta**. Concordo com ele que essa é a melhor abordagem na maioria dos casos, pela simplicidade. Isso também está de acordo com o que já discutimos em [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore)
2. Se é raro ou impossível que uma pergunta se aplique a diferentes versões so software em questão, uma possibilidade é sempre usar somente a tag com o número de versão, e tornar a tag sem versão um sinônimo da atual versão estável. Quando sair uma nova versão, altera-se o sinônimo para apontar para essa nova versão. O Shog9 insiste que isso é uma opção drástica, que só deve ser utilizada quando a maioria esmagadora das perguntas sobre determinado software exigem identificação da versão para que possam ser respondidas. Ele aponta que no SO em inglês somente metade das perguntas sobre o Laravel inclui tag sobre versão específica, ou seja, para a outra metade em teoria a versão não é relevante.