# Tag 'html5' deveria ser 'html-5'?

Tags: debate, status-recusado

Para seguir o padrão discutido em:

[Improvement on Tag System](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/489/improvement-on-tag-system/505#505)

Recentemente foi feito isso para a tag [windows8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows8) também, que virou [windows-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-8). Acho que é a vez do [html5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5).

Comment: Será que deveríamos aplicar essa regra igualmente? HTML5 é frequentemente referido dessa forma mesmo - HTML5, sem espaços. Além disso, dizer "HTML, versão 5" é errôneo, já que esse *standard* ainda não está sequer concluído... Isso me lembra um pouco da época em que falávamos "Java 2" - pelo fato de ter havido mudanças significativas entre o Java `1.1` e o `1.2` (ou foi entre o `1.0` e o `1.1`?). Esse termo continuou sendo empregado mesmo depois que a linguagem seguiu para a versão `1.3`, `1.4`... Ou seja, é mais uma característica de marca (*branding*) do que um simples número de versão.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Verdade. Não tinha pensado nisso.

Comment: De qualquer forma, foi bom ter levantado essa questão, pois podemos estabelecer critérios mais precisos. Vamos ver o que a comunidade pensa sobre isso, e se alguém tem alguma sugestão.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Transforme isso em resposta. Acredito ser isso mesmo, é praticamente um nome por si só, tudo junto.

Comment: isto já está em debate  em http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443/101. Me parece um caso claro de não precisar de hífen. A tecnologia chama HTML5 e não HTML que está na versão 5.

Answer (score 9):

O [FAQ do WHATWG sobre HTML5](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/FAQ#What_is_HTML5.3F) refere-se à norma como "HTML5" (tudo junto, logo **uma só palavra**), não "HTML 5".
A [norma HTML5 do W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) também tem HTML5 escrito tudo junto.

Em contraste, os materiais que eu vi a referirem o Windows 8 têm sempre o "8" separado do "Windows" por um espaço.

Tendo isto em conta, creio que a tag HTML5 devia continuar a ser referida como "html5" e não "html-5".